# copy attributes from xml document to xml document

Tags: xml, function, xslt, copy

I want to select attributes from a xml document and put them into another xml document. In particular, when the content of  in the first document is equal to the content of  in the second document, I want to copy @ana and @lem from the second to the first.

The doc1.xml looks like:

```
<app xml:id="app11">
    <rdg wit="W5 W2 W1 W6 W4 W3"></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W10"><w>s'en</w></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W11"><w>s'en</w></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W8 W7"><w>vait</w> <w>entre</w> <w>lui</w></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W9"><w>va</w></rdg>
</app>
<app xml:id="app12">
    <rdg wit="W5 W2 W1 W6 W9 W4 W8 W3 W7"><w>et</w> <w>sa</w></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W10 W11"><w>aloient</w></rdg>
</app>
<app xml:id="app13">
    <rdg wit="W2 W1 W3"><w>conpaignie</w> <w>tot</w></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W10 W11"></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W5 W6 W9 W4"><w>compaignie</w></rdg>
    <rdg wit="W8 W7"><w>compaigne</w></rdg>
</app>
```

The doc2.xml looks like:

```
<w ana="VER" lem="s'en">s'en</w>
<w ana="PRE" lem="entre">entre</w>
<w ana="PRO:pers" lem="il">lui</w>
<w ana="CON:coord" lem="et">et</w>
<w ana="DET:poss" lem="son">sa</w>
<w ana="NOM" lem="compagnie">compaigne</w>
<w ana="PRO:ind" lem="tot">tout</w>
<w ana="ADJ" lem="droit">droit</w>
<w ana="PRE" lem="apres">apres</w>
<w ana="VER" lem="aler">aloient</w>
<w ana="PRO:ind" lem="tot">tout</w>
<w ana="ADJ" lem="droit">droit</w>
<w ana="VER" lem="aler">vait</w>
<w ana="VER" lem="defendre">deffendre</w>
<w ana="PRE" lem="contre">contre</w>
<w ana="DET:def" lem="le">le</w>
```

I have tried with this XSLT, but it does not work

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="//w">
    <xsl:if test=".[text()]=document(doc2.xml)//w[text()]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="ana">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="document(doc2.xml)//w/@ana"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

<!-- 
<xsl:copy-of select="document(doc2.xml)//w[@ana] and document(doc2.xml)//w[@lem]"></xsl:copy-of>
-->
```

Any suggestion??

Thank you!!

Comment: In what way is it not working?

Comment: Please (1) fix your XML documents, so they are well-formed, (2) show us the expected output of the transformation, and (3) indicate XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: All content won't be processed, you're using `<xsl:copy-of select="."/>` and there's no apply-templates elsewhere that in a template that will never be triggered.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks and the solution.

Answer (score 0):

With such a stylesheet (XSLT 1.0), it may work better:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|@*"></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:variable name="ws" select="document('doc2.xml')" />


<xsl:template match="w">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:if test="$ws//w[text() = current()]">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$ws//w[text() = current()]/@ana" />
    </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Resulting XML will be:

```
  <app xml:id="app11">
      <rdg wit="W5 W2 W1 W6 W4 W3"/>
      <rdg wit="W10">
         <w ana="VER">s'en</w>
      </rdg>
      <rdg wit="W11">
         <w ana="VER">s'en</w>
      </rdg>
      <rdg wit="W8 W7">
         <w ana="VER">vait</w>
         <w ana="PRE">entre</w>
         <w ana="PRO:pers">lui</w>
      </rdg>
      <rdg wit="W9">
         <w>va</w>
      </rdg>
   </app>
   <app xml:id="app12">
      <rdg wit="W5 W2 W1 W6 W9 W4 W8 W3 W7">
         <w ana="CON:coord">et</w>
         <w ana="DET:poss">sa</w>
      </rdg>
      <rdg wit="W10 W11">
         <w ana="VER">aloient</w>
      </rdg>
   </app>
   <app xml:id="app13">
      <rdg wit="W2 W1 W3">
         <w>conpaignie</w>
         <w>tot</w>
      </rdg>
      <rdg wit="W10 W11"/>
      <rdg wit="W5 W6 W9 W4">
         <w>compaignie</w>
      </rdg>
      <rdg wit="W8 W7">
         <w ana="NOM">compaigne</w>
      </rdg>
   </app>
```